# Android - The following classes could not be found: - SubmitText (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Tags: android, xml

When trying to view the Graphical Layout view of my application, I get the following error:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- SubmitText (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

This is my Activity_main xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
         />

    <SubmitText android:id="@+id/Submit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/Submit_text"
        />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"

    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_exit"
    />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know what causes this error message to flag?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `SubmitText` is a custom widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `SubmitText` component in Android. Unless you're using an external library which is supposed to contain `SubmitText`, to avoid future problems you should change it for a common `EditText`.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/Submit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/Submit_text" />
```

Comment: Thanks, thought I could place any field in there, stupid me. Thanks for spotting that!